# sum of query result form two different table that have nothing in common

Tags: sql

hi i have two query result:

```
Table A
Id    u
1     50,00
2     60,00
3     70,00

and 
Table B
id     c
4     110,00    
5     120,01
6     130,02
```

Now i have doing two query on this table and i want sum their query result.

I want update column c from table B with 160 that is sum of(110+50).

```
Table B
Id    c
4     160,00
```

Table B and Table A they have nothing in common.
Now i have doing two query for select their value ed for sum two data:

```
$data=number_format($row['c']+$row1['u']);
$query_updatee="update B set c= (integer)$data where c=110,00";
```

Can i sum the data from two different table that don't have nothing in comon?

```
My output is  pg_query(): Query failed: ERRORE: syntax error at or near "1" LINE 1: update B set punti = (integer)1680,00 where c=110,00 ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\table_A.php on line 81
```

Comment: Do you want to add them in ascending order of id?

Comment: no i want only sum of two data

Comment: but number_format convert string into number but when i upadate data(that is an integer) the database set it to string why?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to fetch the increment.  The rest seems to just be filtering:

```
update B
    set c = c + (select a.u from a where a.id = 1)
    where B.id = 4;
```

Obviously, you can use `where b.c = 110.00` if you want to filter by a number (or use a comma if that is how the database is set up).